# Percentage of Latin loanwords in northern Germanic languages

Tags: latin, germanic-languages, borrowing

What is the percentage of Latin loanwords or words that are of ultimate Latin origin even from intermediate languages in each of the northern Germanic languages? I have noticed that there seem to be quite a few, but searching it up on google either doesn't give a proper number or only gives it for a small sample. I was hoping that perhaps a more accurate number could be acquired from a corpus of text.

Comment: The first thing to consider is this. Are you interested in a percentage of dictionary entries? If so, a large dictionary will have a much larger percentage, because Latinate words are usually less common. Alternatively, are you interested in the percentage of Latin words in an average newspaper article? // Secondly, do you realise that there will be huge differences between languages? English will have a much, much larger percentage than Swedish. // Thirdly, do you count words that were borrowed via an intermediate language, such as French or Italian?

Comment: @Cerberus English isn’t a North Germanic language, so your second point doesn’t really hold as such – but the percentage _will_ be much higher for the continental NG languages than for Faroese and, especially, Icelandic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Fair enough. I saw *northern* without capital, so I guess I assumed it was the general cardinal direction. If the sub-branch was intended, differences will be less pronounced, as you say.

Comment: @Cerberus 1• Perhaps a percentage from a corpus of text. 2• Yes, that is why I wanted to know. 3• Yes. Also, I didn’t realise that not capitalising the “n” would make such a difference.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM: Ad 3: perhaps I was being finicky. // Maybe add those specifications to your question?

Comment: @Cerberus. Swedish has lots of loanwords from German, many of which are themselves borrowed from Latin. This somewhat complicates the concept of "Latin" loanwords.

Comment: You will get more meaningful results if the count is frequency weighted: you should count each occurrence of a given word separately,

Comment: Interesting, but still no place where such data has already been compiled?

Comment: you can get an estimate of the unweighted proportion from wiktionary by comparing the number of unique entries in this category and its subcategories with the number of entries in the swedish lemmas category. This will be a very crude estimate, not including words whose etymology has not been given (or if it has been given but not included in the category) and like I say, won't be frequency weighted, but it will give you somewhere to start. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Swedish_terms_derived_from_Italic_languages